# What url to use for Youtube suggestions

Tags: jquery, xml, json, autocomplete, youtube

I have a script which allows to display Google suggestions over here: [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/epikim/16/edit#javascript,live)

Im trying to do Youtube suggestions instead, so I search the web and found an autocomplete suggestion for Youtube over here: [tikku.com](http://www.tikku.com/jquery-jqtube-util#search_example_4)

The problem is that I really would like to use my own Jquery autocomplete from the JsBin demo because I understand it somehow and it is user friendly.

So I tried replacing the url `http://google.com/complete/search?hl=nl&output=toolbar&q=`

For the one from the example on tikku.com:

```
http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&ds=yt&client=youtube&hjson=t&cp=1&q=s&key=AI39si60UmOiyTb4Pg9kSmqg4Vo2RC290YMztfSKl-vE1eoXj6rDZDgZfT5D7QQ6mKWWeRX5Pjr6hy3dT6OOUcBCTmvHja0mgg&format=5&alt=json&callback=?
```

This doesn't work. What more can I do/try in order to get this working?